# Redeployment fails on Payara 5.194 for java ee 7 application

Tags: java, payara

I migrated EE 6 app to EE 7 on payara 5.194 server and it works fine but randomly upon redeployment, I get the following exception and have no idea why I am getting this. I am not using Roles anywhere in the application.

Exception during lifecycle processing

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type HttpServletResponse with qualifiers @Context
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Context private fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response
  at fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response(RolesPermittedInterceptor.java:0)
 -- WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type HttpServletResponse with qualifiers @Context
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Context private fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response
  at fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response(RolesPermittedInterceptor.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInterceptor(Validator.java:564)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInterceptors(Validator.java:537)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:486)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:496)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.processApplicationLoaded(WeldDeployer.java:514)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:325)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:531)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:538)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:553)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:576)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1878)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1754)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2020-04-16T15:40:38.518-0400] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1587066038518] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app]]

[2020-04-16T15:40:38.529-0400] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00192] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1587066038529] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Undeployment failed for context /app]]

[2020-04-16T15:40:38.564-0400] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1587066038564] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type HttpServletResponse with qualifiers @Context
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Context private fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response
  at fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response(RolesPermittedInterceptor.java:0)
 -- WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type HttpServletResponse with qualifiers @Context
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Context private fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response
  at fish.payara.appserver.cdi.auth.roles.RolesPermittedInterceptor.response(RolesPermittedInterceptor.java:0)
]]
```

Appreciate any help!
Thanks,
Mank

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue? I am facing the exact same error.

Comment: Yes, the issue was due to including some shared jar files that were adding jersey 1.18 dependencies to class path and my project was using jaxrs-ri 2.0 provided by Payara server. Excluding jersey jars resolved the issue.